# How does Leader Snoke enter the room?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, snoke

In The Force Awakens,

> We only see projections of Leader Snoke in a room in which he interacts with Kylo Ren. Leader Snoke's physical body is on some other planet. Not in the room.

So how does Leader Snoke enter the room?

> Does he use the Force to bend space and blend his consciousness into the room? Or does he use technology in the form of a holoprojector of some sort?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Snoke uses a hologram.

He uses a hologram to communicate remotely with Kylo Ren and General Hux. **We even see some dust fall from the ceiling and disrupt the projection a little bit.**

**CANON:** Alan Dean Foster's novelization says

> Seated on the raised platform that was the focus of the chamber was the **blue-tinted holo** of Supreme Leader Snoke.
>
> -Chapter 10

And the *Star Wars: The Force Awakens Visual Dictionary* says

> Snoke's whereabouts are currently unknown as all his known appearances have been done via enlarged **hologram**, and he keeps his command centre mobile, so as to not be tracked.
>
> -page 68

[This page](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snoke) mentions the hologram as well.

> His **hologram** used on the Starkiller base projected him several times larger (around 25 feet) than his natural appearance, towering over Kylo Ren and General Hux.

[image]

The scene closely mirrors a similar scene in *The Empire Strikes Back* in which Vader and Palpatine also communicate via hologram.

[image]

[image]

Comment: No, I don't think mental projections are disrupted by falling dust. Wookieepedia is usually an ok source, but yes it can be wrong.